# Call a Python Main Class Instance from Another Class Without Global

Tags: python, class, instance, call, global

In the code below, an instance of `class A` is created in `main()`.  I want to reference that instance from `class B` without needing to declare `a` as `global`.  How can I do this? (Note - if, you run this script and then run it a second time with `global a` deleted or commented out, make sure the variables are cleared or restart the kernel before running it.  Otherwise, at least in Spyder, the script appears to run OK.)

```
class A():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def start_the_process(self):
        self.b = B()
        self.b.add_values(2, 3)
        
    def print_result(self, result):
        print(result)

class B():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def add_values(self, val1, val2):    
        a.print_result(val1 + val2)
        
def main():
    global a
    a = A()
    a.start_the_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `B` class should receive the `A` object as a parameter, and save it as an attribute.

```
class A():
    
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def start_the_process(self):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.b.add_values(2, 3)
        
    def print_result(self, result):
        print(result)

class B():
    
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    
    def add_values(self, val1, val2):    
        self.a.print_result(val1 + val2)
        
def main():
    a = A()
    a.start_the_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: In reality, class A is a large, complicated class consisting of a custom video player with controls.  Does passing call A into class B copy the instance, or just point to the instance?  Or, does passing class A into class B as an argument induce any performance issues (that you are aware of)?

Comment: It's a reference, just like passing any other parameter. Python never copies anything unless you explicitly tell it to.

Comment: The solution you offered works great for the problem I posted.  Then I realized I didn't adequately document more to my issue that is caused by using a decorator of from an imported package.  I posted another question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66738896/python-decorated-function-cant-update-attribute-from-another-class]