# Python Decorated Function Can't Update Attribute from Another Class

Tags: python, socket.io, decorator

I have an issue using a decorator from a imported package in a class I created.  I created two classes and a `main()`.  An instance of `class A` is created in `main()` and an instance of `class B` is created in `class A`.  `Class B` needs to update attributes of the instance created in `main()`.  Furthermore, I need to use decorators from the imported package.

I don’t know how to get around the inability to reference the attributes of the the instance created in `main()` from the decorated `confirm_connect` function in the instance of `class B`.  The only way I have made it work is to declare the instance created in `main()` as `global` and remove all the `self` references in `class B`.  However, making it `global` causes other issues in my application.  (Making the instance of `socketio` as  `global` within `class B` is tolerable, but I prefer not having it either.)

The function `confirm_connect` receives a message from the server.  If I define the function as `def conform_connect(self, data)`, I get the error message `connect_confirm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'/`.  If I remove `self` from the declaration, then I get the error `NameError: name 'self' is not defined`.

Here is my script.  How can I make my script do what I need it to do?

```
import socketio

class A():

    def __init__(self):
        self.pin = None
        
    def connect_to_server(self):
        self.io = B()
        self.io.connect_to_server()

    def start_the_process(self):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.b.connect_to_server()
        
    def do_something_with_pin(self):
        print(self.pin)

class B():
    
    global sio
    sio = socketio.Client()
    
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
        
    def connect_to_server(self):    
        sio.connect('http://my_url_is_this.org')    
        sio.emit('manual_connection_parameter', {'foo': 'bar'})
            
    @sio.event
    def connect_confirm(data):
        self.a.pin = data
        self.a.do_something_with_pin()
        
def main():
    a = A()
    a.start_the_process()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Stop thinking about the classes, and thing about the instances. We call it *object*-oriented programming, and not *class*-oriented programming, for a reason. Your `B` *instance*, which was created by a method of your `A` instance, needs to be able to interact with that `A` *instance*; therefore, it needs to know which one it was. Therefore it needs some kind of reference. Such as the one that you pass to `B.__init__`, when you do `self.b = B(self)`. That system should work fine. Just apply it consistently; what's the problem?

Comment: It comes across that the *actual* problem you are experiencing is in defining `connect_confirm` (is it `connect_confirm`, or `confirm_connect`? You need to pay attention to these things; if you give functions different names when you talk about the code than when you actually write the code, it shows your inattention) in a way that meets the expectations of the `socketio` module.

Comment: So - what happened when you read the documentation? It seems that it's expecting `@sio.event` to decorate a plain function, rather than an instance method. Did it say anything about that? Did it suggest any workarounds?

Comment: `global sio` that makes no sense in a class definition.

Comment: Now that I have an answer written up, I realize that this is actually a very good question about general technique, with an answer that's "only obvious if you're Dutch". It probably comes up in a lot of other contexts, which makes me want to write it up in a more general manner so I have a good duplicate target....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you understand how decorators work, then you understand that

```
@sio.event
def connect_confirm(self, data):
    self.a.pin = data
    self.a.do_something_with_pin()
```

is simply syntactic sugar for

```
def connect_confirm(self, data):
    self.a.pin = data
    self.a.do_something_with_pin()
connect_confirm = sio.event(connect_confirm)
```

And the reported problem is that `sio.event` expects a 1-argument, plain callback function that will receive the `data`; so with a `self` parameter it doesn't meet those expectations (and without a `self` parameter, the expectations *of the method* aren't met).

The insight is that (since 3.x; 2.x did things differently under the hood) a method defined in a class is *just a function*; it's the *process of looking up that method from an instance* that makes methods do the special things with `self` that they do.

So when you decorate the method, you end up registering totally the wrong thing as a callback. The `socketio.Client` doesn't know anything about your B instance and can't work with it, no matter what you do.

The solution is to instead use *the bound instance method of your instance* for the callback, which requires us to invoke the decorator manually as described at the beginning.

In the `__init__`, we can do something like:

```
def __init__(self, a):
    self.a = a
    sio.event(self.connect_confirm)
```

And then we can define that method normally:

```
def connect_confirm(self, data):
    self.a.pin = data
    self.a.do_something_with_pin()
```

Notice how in the `__init__` context we can now write `self.` when we do the "decoration", so we tell the `socketio.Client` to use the `connect_confirm` *of this instance* as a callback. We don't need to do anything with the "decorated" result, so we don't assign it anywhere.

---

It's worth considering what this kind of thing looks like from the API's point of view. The `socketio.Client` class implementation presumably includes something like:

```
class Client:
    # ... lots of other stuff...
    def event(self, callback):
        self._event_callback = callback
        return callback
    def _some_internal_logic(self):
        if _special_situation_occurs():
            self._event_callback(self._get_data_for_callback())
```

If the implementation didn't `return callback`, it would be obvious what you needed to do in your situation, since the decorator syntax wouldn't have been available. (Well, you *can* use anything as a decorator; but getting back `None` or another non-function is not very useful most of the time.)

Comment: You should also strongly consider how you manage your instances of `socketio.Client`. It probably makes more sense for each `B` instance to either create its own `socketio.Client`, or have one passed to `__init__` from `A`, which can in turn create its own or receive one depending on your needs. Just throwing globals around will bite you in the long run; read up on `dependency injection`.

Comment: Great explanation!  This works perfectly!  There now is a class for each SocketIO listener.  A `socketio.Client` object is created in `A` and passed into the `__init__` of each of the listener.